# I want to highlight a word if it is not followed by another specific word using VB

Tags: vba, ms-office, cpu-word

So I'm a total newbie when it comes to using VB. I am trying to highlight a word when it is not followed by another specific word within the next two words. I tried the following code but it seems to just the first word. Many thanks in advance.

```
    Sub fek()
'
' 
'
'
 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "n."
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute

    If Selection.Find.Found = True Then
        With Selection.Range
        
        .MoveStart wdWord, 2
        
        End With
        
        With Selection.Find
        .Text = "fek"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
                    End With
                    
                    End If
                    
        If Selection.Find.Found = False Then
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do what you want. You need to bear in mind that what Word defines as a `Word` can be different to what a human would, e.g. an IP address is counted as 7 words!

```
Sub fek()
   Dim findRange As Range
   Dim nextWords As Range
   
   Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
   With findRange.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = "n."
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   
      Do While .Execute = True
         'findRange is now the range of the match so set nextWords to the 2 next words
         Set nextWords = findRange.Next(wdWord)
         nextWords.MoveEnd wdWord, 3
         'look for the specific text in the next two words
         If InStr(nextWords.Text, "fek") = 0 Then findRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
         'collapse and move findRange to the end of the match
         findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
         findRange.Move wdWord, 4
      Loop
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Just change `nextWords.MoveEnd wdWord` to `nextWords.MoveEnd wdWord, 3`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code seemed to work intially but it seems that it highlights the word regardless of whether the fek word is nearby. I expanded the range based on what you said about how word counts words but still it seems to make no difference. I am using this in Greek- I don't know if that might be a problem but it works fine with other code pieces.

Comment: Please see edited answer. I initially misunderstood what you wanted and when I realised you wanted to highlight the initial word only if the following word *wasn't* present I quickly reversed the logic, forgetting that `InStr` wouldn't then evaluate to True / False. The code in my answer works in my testing, though I am not testing it on Greek text.

Comment: That works perfectly and in Greek too. I am really grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The following would probably be significantly faster if there are many 'n.' strings in the document:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
i = Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Text = "n."
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Replacement.Highlight = False
    .Text = "n.[^s ]@fek"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "n.[^s ]@[!^s ]@fek"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "n.[^s ]<[!^s ]@>[^s ]@fek"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "n.[^s ]<[!^s ]@>[^s ]@[!^s ]@fek"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```