# How can I check if the next word is numerical to determine action

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

So after Timothy Rylatt helped me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353326/i-want-to-highlight-a-word-if-it-is-not-followed-by-another-specific-word-using/64354669?noredirect=1#comment113858501_64354669) question I am now having another problem. I only want to highlight the first word if the word that follows is numerical. I have tried to do so but it does not seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated and apologies if I am making any obvious errors I am (VERY) new to VB.

```
Sub feknew()
   Dim findRange As Range
   Dim nextWords As Range
   Dim NumChk  As Range
   
   Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
   With findRange.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = "í. "
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      
      Set NumChk = findRange.Next(wdWord)
      If IsNumeric(NumChk) Then
      
                                   
         Do While .Execute = True
         'findRange is now the range of the match so set nextWords to the 2 next words
         Set nextWords = findRange.Next(wdWord)
         nextWords.MoveEnd wdWord, 3
         'look for the specific text in the next two words
         If InStr(nextWords.Text, "á") = 0 Then findRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
         'collapse and move findRange to the end of the match
         findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
         findRange.Move wdWord, 4
      
      Loop
         End If
         End With
         End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what part is not working? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this which seems to be working except for the fact that using a parenthesis or a quote sign do not work in my string but if I use a word instead it works fine:

```
Sub feknew()
     Dim findRange As Range
     Dim nextWords As Range
     Dim textToFind As String
        
   Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
   With findRange.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = "n. "
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      
            
      Do While .Execute = True
         If IsNumeric(findRange.Next(wdWord).Text) Then
         Set nextWords = findRange.Next(wdWord)
         nextWords.MoveEnd wdWord, 4
         'look for the specific text in the next two words
        If InStr(nextWords.Text, "(A'") = 0 Then findRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
         'collapse and move findRange to the end of the match
         findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
         findRange.Move wdWord, 4

      End If
      Loop
   End With
```

Comment: The parenthesis needs to be inside the quotes, i.e. "(A')" not "(A'")

Comment: I did not do that by mistake, as I said in my other comment the citation is usually eg (A' 245) but of course the number changes each time so I can only put that part in the string. In any case, I resolved this by putting another word before this part and then deleting it in the script.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I was looking at the formatting SO applied to the code in your answer and didn't read it properly.

Comment: No worries, I wouldn't have reached a solution without your help, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple - you don't even need a macro:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
i = Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Text = "í.[^s ]@[0-9,.]{1,}>"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Neither does a macro need a loop.

Comment: This would indeed be the correct approach if the desired result was highlighting both the text and the number. However, it is my understanding, from the previous question, that the desired result is that only the text is highlighted, not the number.

Comment: In which case, as per my post in the other thread, a second F/R could be used to remove the unwanted highlighting. And, as per my comments in that thread such an approach is likely to be far faster than indiscriminately looping through all the mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because you have added the numeric test in the wrong place. At that point the `Find` hasn't been executed and `findRange` points to the entire document. The test needs to be within the loop, just as it was in the routine you were editing.

As you only need to examine the next word there is no need to introduce a new variable, `NumChk`.

The routine should probably also be made a little more generic so that you don't need to edit it for each string you want to highlight.

```
Sub UsageExample()
   HighlightIfFollowedByNumber "text"
End Sub

Sub HighlightIfFollowedByNumber(textToFind As String)
   Dim findRange As Range
   
   Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
   With findRange.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = textToFind
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      
      Do While .Execute = True
         If IsNumeric(findRange.Next(wdWord).Text) Then findRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
         findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
         findRange.Move wdWord
      Loop
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I obviously did not explain this correctly- I do not want to highlight the word if the following word is numeric. What I want to do is do what we did with the last code but only if the next word is not numeric. This has to do with legal documents: we usually cite a law as [n.] (which stands for law in greek) [law number/year] [(government gazette number)], eg n. 4412/2014 (A' 246). So I want to exclude the case where a sentence ends with a word ending in n being highlighted.

Comment: @MANOL - that is simple to change. Just change `If IsNumeric` to `If Not IsNumeric`. If you make the search string " n. " then you can avoid finding sentences that end with a word ending in n

Comment: That's an option indeed but then I also need to carry out the search we did with the previous code. I think the answer I posted covers both issues.